# How to set the fonts of the latex file?

Tags: formatting, margins

I am a newbie in LaTeX. I am editing a paper, which is two column. The first paragraph of the paper is the abstract. I want my abstract to satisfy the following requirement:

> The abstract should appear at the top of the left-hand column of text,
>   about 0.5 inch (12 mm) below the title area and no more than 3.125
>   inches (80 mm) in length. Leave a
>   0.5 inch (12 mm) space between the end of the abstract and the beginning of the main text.

The tile must satify:

> The paper title (on the first page) should begin 1.38 inches (35 mm)
>   from the top edge of the page, centered, completely capitalized, and
>   in Times 14-point, boldface type. The authors’ name(s) and
>   affiliation(s) appear below the title in capital and lower case
>   letters. Papers with multiple authors and affiliations may require two
>   or more lines for this information.

The content must satify:

> All printed material, including text, illustrations, and charts, must
>   be kept within a print area of 7 inches (178 mm) wide by 9 inches (229
>   mm) high. Do not write or print anything outside the print area. The
>   top margin must be 1 inch (25 mm), except for the title page, and the
>   left margin must be
>   0.75 inch (19 mm). All text must be in a two-column format. Columns are to be 3.39 inches (86 mm) wide, with a
>   0.24 inch (6 mm) space between them. Text must be fully justified.

I just use the normal IEEE template. I do not know how to specify the LaTeX in order to satisfy the above requirements.

Can anyone help me about this? Thank you!

Comment: How are the title and the content of the question related? Also you can add `\vspace{0.5in}` after the abstract to add half an inch of space.

Comment: @PTNobel, I modified the questions. Please give me an answer! I will vote!!

Comment: @Shawn just use the files provided by the conference organizers (I am not sure if this is exactly the conference you are submitting to; there were many places on the web using the same requirements word-for-word). Check here for the files and examples of use: http://www.cmsworldwide.com/ICASSP2011/papers/PaperKit.html#Templates

Comment: @PaulGessler, This is not the one I will submit. There is no template for the one I will submit. I want to learn how to write latex code to satify these requirements, not just find a template. Can you write an answer for my question, so that I can learn how to specify the fonts in latex? Thank you so much!

Comment: How will you learn if one of us just does it for you? Your question is too broad for this site, I think. If you really want to learn, start with [`clsguide`](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/clsguide.pdf) and ask more focused questions as you run into problems. However, I don't think you need to write a new class: Even if that conference isn't your specific one; the requirements you listed are also met by that package, so you could use it and modify (changing the name, of course) if there are further requirements you haven't listed here.

Comment: @PaulGessler, can you just write a sample latex for these requirements? I just want to know how to specify them.I learn latex from this webiste most of the time. I will vote it! Thank you so much!

Comment: The linked template will show you how to do it. Why do you especially want somebody to duplicate information here? That site provides a complete working example including sample document and formatting files (package, BibTeX style etc.) What is the point of copying stuff here?

Comment: The first thing to do is ask if they have a `sty` file that meets those requirements.  If not, the `scrartcl` document class from `koma-script` should be configurable to get what you want.  You can also set borders with `geometry`.  To get (a clone of) Times, you can use the `tgtermes` package, or `newtxfonts`.

Comment: @Lorehead, can you use other package to set all the fonts above without using "sty"  and write an answer here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work has already been done, in a package called `spconf`. Why reinvent the wheel? If you want to learn, study the contents/comments of the already-written package and ask specific questions as they come up. The format of this site isn't really meant for this broad of a question. It's better to break the problem into its individual parts, search for a solution, and ask a question if you can't find one. If everyone just asks for a turn-key solution for their document, the content isn't really reusable for others, and good answers would be too long.

---

There appears to be no official distribution channel for `spconf.sty`, hence I found many many copies of it online. At a [page for a conference called ICASSP 2012](http://www.cmsworldwide.com/ICASSP2011/papers/PaperKit.html#Templates), I found a copy of `spconf.sty` along with a complete example and instructions for author use. Not sure what this adds over the example provided with the package, but here it is anyway:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{spconf} % downloaded from the web, since this is not on CTAN

\usepackage{blindtext} % just for the example

\title{Title of the paper}
\name{Shawn \thanks{Thanks to \TeX\ StackExchange\dots}}
\address{University, address, location, etc.} % use \\ to separate lines within \address

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract for my paper.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the link you give it to me. There are other files: IEEEbib.bst, strings.bib, refs.bib. How to use these files?

Comment: @Shawn see the template tex file also included. Near the end of that, two lines of code show how these files are involved: `\bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}` tells LaTeX to use `IEEEbib.bst` to format the bibliography and \bibliography{strings,refs}` loads two bibliographic database files (`strings.bib` and `refs.bib`).

Comment: In my side, when I use your latex code, there is error pointed to "\maketitle". The error is: LaTex Error: There is no line here to end. See the LaTex manual or LaTex Companion for explanation. Type H<return> for immediate help. How to fix this error?

Comment: @Shawn no idea, sorry.

Comment: I cannot get rid of the error! But I will still vote your answer  for you